# How to handle git branch hierarchy

Tags: git, github, branch

I have a git repository, with the `master` branch that is the main one.

I have a hierarchy in the following way:

```
      master
        |
       core
  /     |     \
 V100  V200  V300
```

`V100`, `V200`, `V300` are different modules that depend on core.

Multiple persons will be working on these modules, and also be modifying the `core` module from any of the `V*` branches.

The problem is that I don't really know how to handle this situation without copying the files, changing to the core branch, modifying it, then pulling the changes from the `V*` branches.

Is there a better way of handling these changes ? Or should the core module never be modified from withing a `V*` branch ?

**Note:** The `core` module cannot be tested stand-alone, it just contains abstract classes, interfaces and libraries used in the other branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have confused branching with a way of maintaining different modules. Branches should be versions of the same code.

For example You may have a master, development, and several feature branches. Your master branch is you code as you have it deployed. Your development branch might be the code you are preparing for deployment. And your feature branches are your new, unfinished features.

As you finish a feature you merge its branch into the development branch. Once you have your release ready you merge your development branch back into master and release your code. And so on it goes like a cycle.

Generally I find it's best to keep separate groups of code in separate repositories. So it sounds to me like you'd want a repo for each of your V* modules. You would also have a repo for the Core module. In git it is common to have many repos like this.

Optionally you could include the Core module into the other repos as a submodule. What you do is create a directory in your main module, say V100/core, and then set this up as a submodule. This then links to a specific commit of the Core repo. In this way you can be certain that your projects link to a version of the submodule that works for them.

Submodules do have some intricacies and gotchas, and because of this they have a bad name. I find when used properly they actually work very well. To read more about them check out http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules